# Ошибка при работе с Pywapi: "xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError: syntax error: line 1, column 0"

Tags: python

Я хочу создать телеграмм бота, который должен получать информацию о погоде через pywapi. но вылезает ошибка:

код модуля: https://ideone.com/KdiXI4

Содержание xml_response:
`b'This service is deprecated as of 01/15/2020'`

Если устарела услуга, значит нельзя никак пользоваться?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "py.py", line 5, in <module>
    lookups = pywapi.get_location_ids(city)
  File "C:\Users\bekse\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pywapi.py", line 825, in get_location_ids
    loc_id_data = get_loc_id_from_weather_com(search_string)
  File "C:\Users\bekse\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pywapi.py", line 875, in get_loc_id_from_weather_com
    dom = minidom.parseString(xml_response)
  File "C:\Users\bekse\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\xml\dom\minidom.py", line 1969, in parseString
    return expatbuilder.parseString(string)
  File "C:\Users\bekse\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\xml\dom\expatbuilder.py", line 925, in parseString
    return builder.parseString(string)
  File "C:\Users\bekse\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\xml\dom\expatbuilder.py", line 223, in parseString
    parser.Parse(string, True)
xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError: syntax error: line 1, column 0
```

Comment: На 875 строке есть `dom = minidom.parseString(xml_response)`, до этой строки выведите `print(xml_response)` и добавьте в вопросе (кнопка `править` под вопросом). Стопудов, в этой строке что-то нехорошее пришло

Comment: подправил, `b'This service is deprecated as of 01/15/2020'`

Comment: Ну вот, что еще тут говорить :) Сервис по ссылке `LOCID_SEARCH_URL     = ` устаревший, ищите аналог этой библиотеки. А мб, что авторы этой библиотеки обновили ее, а вы используете старую версию?

Comment: Нет, это самая последняя версия, жаль что проект умер

Comment: Оформите, пожалуйста, ответ, указав причину ошибки :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pywapi уже не поддерживается, поэтому остается только найти аналог этой библиотеки